# Ignore Case with BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using BitBucket with Git and would like to know how to configure GitIgnore on Bitbucket to ignore case sensitivity. Basically, the programming language that is being used automatically changes case of some words such as enumerations and some declared variables, I would like to be able to change the case of words without marking them as modified in any manner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tag the question gitignore. But gitignore is about filenames. But if you talk about variables you probably mean file contents.

Whichever you really mean, the answer should be the same. Git can absolutely not be made to ignore differences in character case, neither in filenames nor in file contents. Git computes SHA1 checksums over contents and filenames internally. And SHA1 values will always be completely different if the casing of any character changes.

To get rid of annoying differences, which are just caused by changed character case, you need to "normalize" all spelling before check-in. Define what is the "normal" spelling for you, and define a pre-commit hook in git (your favorite search engine will find information about git hooks). In its primitive form the hook might reject "non-normalized" input and you need to call a "normalizer" manually before the commit succeeds. You could also use use clean and smudge filters to build something. But that's a toolbox, not a ready solution. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes (I never had to do anything similar). If you use a reasonably smart editor, it might be better to automate the normalization there on each save operation.

Addition/Correction: Actually git has some support for ignoring case in filenames.
See [`core.ignorecase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)
It is not very clearly documented (quote "enables various workarounds"). I have never needed to use it so I can't tell more.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I ended up using SmartGit to ignore cases, since I could not address the problem directly.

Comment: I'm on a team working with a legacy codebase and legacy toolset wihich randomly changes case of certain variables when saving documents. Very annoying that we can't ignore those when doing code reviews in BitBucket.